# Identifying and replacing laptop motherboard connector

Tags: connector, identification, soldering, ribbon-cable

My laptop was having cooling issues, to I opened it up to clean the fan. When attempting to start it up afterwards, nothing happened, and soon after I smelled burnt plastic. Upon inspection I discovered that the ribbon cable connecting the power button to the motherboard was burnt. I must have put in a little off, and two connectors shorted. There doesn't seem to be any other damage, so I figure if I can replace the wire and the connector on the motherboard (it's ruined as well) the laptop should return to its former glory.

- I've identified the cable as `cvilux e208903-5 awm 20706 105c 60v vw-1`
- How can I go about identifying the connector on the motherboard?
- Is it advisable/possible to cut the burnt part of the wire, and strip the remainder? Or am I better off [replacing the wire](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=cvilux%20e208903%20awm%2020706%20105c%2060v%20vw-1&_sop=12&_fspt=1&_mPrRngCbx=1&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=cvilux%20e208903-5%20awm%2020706%20105c%2060v%20vw-1&_sacat=0) altogether?
- I've soldered electronics before, but this a lot smaller than anything I've ever dealt with. Is it doable? What should I be looking out for?

[image: Burnt wire]
[image: Burnt connector][image]

Comment: Check Wurth zif connectors.

Comment: Consider taking it to someone who has the skills and equipment - unless you can afford to loose it....

Comment: Are you sure you didn't fry the motherboard in the process?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum that seems to be the connector!

Comment: @SolarMike If I can find someone in my area, that's definitely what I'm planning on doing

Comment: @winny I can't _see_ any other damage on the motherboard that the moment, but other than that, I'm unsure.

Comment: If you find the right wurth, they will send you samples. Just ask.